# objective-c equivalent to java anonymouse interface implementation

Tags: objective-c, interface, anonymous-class

I hope the title is precise enough.
I was wondering, how I can pass a interface implementation to an object in objc language.

In java it would look like:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void onData();
}
```

The implementing class

```
public class ImplementMyInterface {

    // ...
    // other methods
    ///

    void registerInterface(){
         MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface(){
             @Override
             public void onData(){
               // process data here within the class
             }
           }; 
     }
}
```

And in objc?
id myinterface.

How to implement it in the class?
Is there only the possibility to let the class inherit the interface?
Like

```
interface MyInterface : NSObject
```

and the implementing class

```
MyImplementingClass : MyInterface
```

Or is there another possibility?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not an anonymous interface. It's an anonymous class implementing that interface. Objective-C does not allow any anonymous classes. Also, since Objective-C has no GC, you actually have to retain the delegate somehow. You cannot just pass it without actually saving it to some local variable.

Comment: @Sulthan can you please have a look at my posted answer.
Does it comply with your hint of the delegate?
If not, could you please explain it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C has anonymous functions (blocks), but it doesn't have anonymous classes. So, the only way to implement a protocol (which is the objective-c term for an interface) is to make some class conform to that protocol (using your terminology, make that class "inherit" from that protocol) and add a protocol implementation inside that class' implementation.

Comment: Hi FreeNickname,

Comment: Hi @Johan, I'm afraid, the second part of your comment disappeared :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem.
I was only able to import the MyInterface header file in my ImplementMyInterface.m file, but rather in the ImplementMyInterface.h file.
So everything I could do was inside the ImplementMyInterface.m file.

```
// ImplementMyInterface.m
#import "MyInterface.h"

// inner class
@interface MyInternalInterface : NSObject<MyInterface>
@property (retain) ImplementMyInterface * implementation;
@end

// the actual class 
@implementation ImplementMyInterface
MyInternalInterface * _internalInterface;

+(instancetype) build {
  // construct myself
  ImplementMyInterface * implementatMyInterface = [[ImplementMyInterface alloc] init];

  // init inner class object
  _internalInterface = [[MyInternalInterface alloc] init];

  // register myself
  [_internalInterface setImplementation:implementatMyInterface];

  return implementatMyInterface;
}


- (NSString *) theActualData {
    return @"The actual data";
}







// end of implementation class
@end

// implementation of inner class
@implementation MyInternalInterface
@synthesize implementation;

- (NSString *) onData {
    if(implementation != nil)
        return [implementation theActualData];

    return @"";
}
// end of ImplementMyInterface.m
```